# Handling null and NSDate in dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdictionary

I have some data stored in an object say objectA. When I print objectA it looks like:

```
{
  employeeId = 1234;
  startDate = (null);
  endDate = 2013-10-01 04:59:59 +0000;
}
```

I am storing it in a dictionary as below:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"employee_id" : objectA.employeeId,
                       @"start_date" : objectA.startDate,
                       @"end_date" : objectA.endDate};
```

I get a crash when I step over the dict code because I am trying to insert a nil object in dict. `Error : attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]`

Also is this the correct way to pass the date to a dictionary because when I pass this dictionary through isValidJson check, the app crashes again.

Am I doing anything wrong here? How do I handle null/nil check while passing the data to a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your date is nil, either don't include it in that entry in the dictionary (then when you try and read that key you will get back a nil result) or use `[NSNull null]` as a placeholder object (or whatever null placeholder constant you may want to use - like a specific string @"thisismynullstringconstant") and then when you read your null value from the dictionary convert it to nil.

Comment: `[NSNull null]` is the right option, the "whatever custom string constant" approach is *very* fragile.

Comment: Totally agree. I'm just saying it's a technical option if there was some business logic to it.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Another option would be to actually **allow** dictionaries to contain `nil` values by using custom callbacks of `CFMutableDictionaryRef` and relying on toll-free bridging.

Comment: Toll-free bridging is not guaranteed to work if you use custom CF callbacks.

Comment: You should consider using the `?:` operator to nil-coallace the values for your dictionary.